# How to access the relative parent directory using <filesystem> in C++

Tags: c++, file, directory, c++17

I'm wanting to know how to access the parent directory of the current working directory using the `<filesystem>` header for `C++ 17`. I then want to redirect to another folder from the parent directory to search for a file.

Here's a conceptual example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;

    fs::path working_dir(fs::current_path());

    fs::path parent_path(
        // ... Get path to parent dir of current working dir ... //
        );

    fs::current_path(parent_path);
    fs::current_path(
        // ... Redirect to subfolder called "sub_fold" ... //
        );

    // ... Search for specified file called "sub_file" to see if it exists ... //
    if (sub_file.exists())  // Psudo-code for returning if "sub_file" exists
    {
        // ... Do stuff with "sub_file" ... //
    }
    else cout << "File does not exist in " << fs::current_path << endl;

    fs::current_path(working_dir);

    // ... Continue program ... //
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`working_dir.parent_path()` will get you to the parent directory - but make sure to check if it exists first.

`working_dir / "sub_fold"` should get you to the subdirectory.

This information courtesy of [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path)

Comment: Thanks. In regards to the second part, the specific syntax would be something like `fs::current_path(working_dir.parent_path() / "sub_fold");` right?

Comment: You need to declare your variables correctly. `fs::path current_path`, for example, declares a variable named `current_path` of type `fs::path`.  As far as I know, there is no `fs::current_path` call.